# Centering text in `<option>` elements (Webkit & IE)

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, html-select, centering

I have a `<select>` element:

```
<select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

And I give it a width and center it:

```
select {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The centering only happens in Firefox, not Webkit or IE. ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lsq6/))

How can I center the options in Webkit and Internet Explorer?

Comment: Are you just trying to align what's selected, or all of the options? You could use `select#budget { text-indent: 115px; }` for the former. You can modify the value slightly to get the centering effect you want. And a heads up, the center HTML tags are deprecated in HTML 4.01 and unsupported in HTML 5.

Comment: I'm trying to center bother the selected and all of the options.

Comment: Well, I can't think of much except padding and text-indent. Would that work for you?

Comment: Or a quick fix - you can use &nbsp; to space it out. Otherwise, select and other form elements are rendered not in the same way as block elements, so you can't control them with text-align or similar properties. Text-indent and the above "fix" could get you closer to what you envision, but otherwise, you'll have to go beyond by making custom form elements, etc. JS/jQuery works too, if you can find the right methods.

Comment: [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220113/should-big-edits-be-approved) for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At my knowledges, I suggest you to create your own select-like element instead of trying to center the select button as a workaround. You can do it using javascript (jQuery here, you can still do it using pure javascript, which will be a faster code).

html :

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-title">Dropdown menu</div>

    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="option">Option 1</div>
        <div class="option">Option 2</div>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" class="dropdown-select" />
</div>
```

css :

```
.dropdown-title {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
}
.option {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

js :

```
$('.dropdown-title').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
});
$('.option').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').hide();
    $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-title').html($(this).html());
    $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-select').val($(this).html());
});
```

Using jQuery in this case : http://jsfiddle.net/U44Yr/

Comment: Because you can't really center without using tricks. Sure you can text-indent or add spaces but it's not centering. If he wants to, this is the only solution. I'm not saying it is the best way for all cases ;) !

Comment: "I can't figure it out" !== "Let's slow our page down with jQuery"

Comment: Never said he has to use jQuery. This was just a solution to explain him. "Using jQuery in this case". He can still use pure javascript.

Comment: Actually, you did. An answer is an answer. No need to include irrelevant code. At worst, you should be using vanilla JS. But, really, this is a CSS question. If you can't write a good answer, just don't answer.

Comment: I said that it can't be done using CSS. That's true. You can use tricks like text-indent but it is not a real center because it won't fit to all cases (he will have to adjust each time he wants to center). My solution is just a possibility that I suggest.

Comment: Obviously don't post those bad answers either, but maybe there is another way that isn't immediately obvious. (Think div -> pacman with css)

Comment: Maybe, but why do you have to be so rude? I'm pretty new to Stackoverflow (I just asked questions before), if I did something wrong, I'm sorry, just trying to help.

Comment: Well, ok fine. Just try to stick to the question's tags in the future (unless it's impossible).

Comment: Ok, do you suggest I delete my post?

Comment: Nah. Reword it so it's like "One solution is making your own custom element" or something. Now it starts with "You can't do it with pure HTML/CSS.", which may be right, but we shouldn't jump to conclusions. It should also not that this is not a _solution_, but a _workaround_ (and the answer should treat itself as a workaround; workarounds that claim to be solutions are often voted down).

Comment: @bjb568 - "If you can't write a good answer, just don't answer" - What? No. You can use your votes to vote up answers you agree with, or vote down answers you disagree with, but you should not discourage users from attempting to answer.  Suggestions for improvement are fine, but please be careful not to cross the line into dictating what answers must be. Remember you are free to add your own answer if you think you can do better.

Comment: @Chris There is a line somewhere. It's definitely before "I don't know" and definitely after "You can use X library".